# Cascade in Firebase Realtime Database's Security rule

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    "USER":{
      "$uid":{
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid && auth.uid != null",
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid && auth.uid != null",
        
        "DELETE_ARTICLE":{
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid && auth.uid != null",
            ".read": false
        },
        "FOLDER":{
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid && auth.uid != null",
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid && auth.uid != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the user read their field in "USER/{$uid}" but not in "USER/{uid}/DELETE_ARTICLE".
But because of cascade condition, I couldn't do that.
What should I do.

Answer (score 1):

As you've found [permission cascades downwards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#read_and_write_rules_cascade): **once you've given somebody read or write permission on a certain node, you can't take that permission away at a lower level.**

This means that if you want different permissions on parts of the data, you'll need to put those parts in separate branches of your database. For example, you could:

```
USER: {
  "$uid": {
    ...
  }
},
DELETE: {
  "$uid": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now you can grant separate permissions on `/USER/$uid` and `/DELETE/$uid`.

---